# checkbox handling php multiple checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox, form-submit

Working on a simple php code. When it press on only PH it show hello, and only on chlorine it show yello. When both is pressed it show sello.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach($_POST['verdi'] as $animal){

       if(isset($_POST['verdi[]==PH']))

       {
        echo "hello";
       }
    }
}
?>




  <form name="input" action="" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="verdi[]" value="PH">PH<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="verdi[]" value="Chlorine">Chlorine<br>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you using an array, just give them different names, it'll be much easier to check that way.

Comment: Why is your PHP mixed in with your HTML with not <?php ?> delimiters?

Comment: Musa, can you please show me how to do it ?  Zarathuztra, sorry. My bad..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])  && is_array($_POST['verdi'])) {
    $checked = array();
    foreach($_POST['verdi'] as $animal) {
         // you can do extra validation here.
         $checked[] = $animal;
    }


    if(in_array("PH", $checked) && in_array("Chlorine", $checked)) {
        echo "sello";
    } else {
      if(in_array("PH", $checked)) {
        echo "hello";
      } else if(in_array("Chlorine", $checked)) {
        echo "yello";
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first line is missing a `)` should be `if(isset($_POST['submit'])  && is_array($_POST['verdi'])){` otherwise it will throw a parse error.

Comment: indeed... but I am not using IDE and just adding answer here as fast as I can alongside my office work. correcting it.

Comment: I'm not using an IDE either, didn't need one for this one ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple check in PHP:

```
if( in_array("PH", $_POST["verdi"]) ){
  echo "in array!";
}
```